# This 5-d numpy array takes up hardly no RAM if shuffled

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory

I have some images stored in chunks of 80 in a numpy array.

```
trainImages.shape
# (715, 80, 96, 96, 3)
```

For example `trainImages` has got 715 chunks with each 80 images of size (96,96,3).

The array is `dtype=float32` so it takes up quite a lot of space in RAM, approximately 6GB.

I shuffle the chunks with this code

```
shuffler = np.random.permutation(trainImages.shape[0])
trainImages = trainImages[shuffler]
```

I notice that the RAM usage drops to almost 0. The shape is still the same and I can display the images. All and all the array looks fine but it hardly takes up any RAM after the shuffle. How can it be?

I'm using Google Colab Pro with 25GB of RAM and I monitor the RAM usage from the indicator at the top.

You can easily reproduce this behavior by pasting this code in a Colab notebook

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(715, 80, 96, 96, 3).astype(np.float32)
shuffler = np.random.permutation(a.shape[0])
a = a[shuffler]
```

I've also tried to shuffle the same array, but reshaped to `(57200,96,96,1)` so I was suffling every image. In this case I didn't notice any change in RAM usage, as expected.

Comment: Does Google Colab display the amount of swap usage?

Comment: Well looks like that there isn't any swap...

Comment: Can you check carefully what exactly "almost 0" is? I suspect that it's actually 6GB dropping from something like 18GB.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running out of memory. Generally when slicing in numpy, the result is a view which does not take up a lot of memory. However when slicing with a boolean mask or a random array of integers there is no regularity so numpy will not return a view but rather a copy. In the line:

```
a = a[shuffler]
```

Python will first allocate a new 6GB array, then copy the data according to the index in `shuffler` to the new array and finally reassign the new array to the old one releasing the memory of the old one. However it will have to have 12GB allocated at one point! I suspect that Colab, only having ~13GB kills the python kernel that tries to allocate more memory than allowed. As a result, you see the RAM dropping to 0.

I am not quite sure why the reshaped array works, perhaps when you tested it, you had more available memory so you just barely managed to fit into the 13GB.

However what you can do to shuffle the samples more memory efficiently is to use

```
np.random.shuffle(a)
```

This method will shuffle the first axis of your data in place which should prevent the issue with memory overflow.

If you need to shuffle the first axis of two different arrays in a consistent order (for example the input features `x` and output labels `y`), you can set a seed before  each suffle ensuring that the two shuffles are equivalent:

```
np.random.seed(42)
np.random.shuffle(x)
np.random.seed(42)
np.random.shuffle(y)
```

Comment: I'm using Colab Pro and I have 25GB of RAM. Also I have tried with a smaller array and I still can notice the RAM usage going up and down again. I will try `np.random.shuffle`. Thanks for the tip.